# Not able to load sass file Rails 3.1.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, sass, rails-engines

I imported a css.sass file which in turn has :

```
@import "mountable_engine/file.sass"
```

But due to some weird reason some of the sass files are found and for some I get the  following error :

> **ActionView::Template::Error (File to import not found or unreadable:
>   mountable_engine/file1.sass**

How can I get rid of this error?

**EDIT : ** This is happening within a mountable engine

Comment: Is it `file.sass` or `file1.sass`

Comment: I am able to load file.sass but file1.sass is not loading

Comment: What is your directory structure and where are you importing file1.sass?

Comment: In the vendors folder there is a mountable engine. The file1.sass is in the stylesheets folder of the mountable engine in vendors folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it was my own mistake. There was an issue with pre-compiling assets so somehow that file was left out by rails. After clearing the rails cache folder and re-running assets precompile my issue was solved.

Answer (score 0):

SCSS imports are relative to the file doing the importing, I presume that SASS are the same.

If both files are in the same directory try

```
@import "file.sass"
```

Edit: Sorry, misread question. this probably doesn't help.